# Copying / Pasting Data From One Excel to Another - Dropbox/Combobox error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from one Excel workbook to another.

We had a change in the template of an import file, and it has thus ruined the old import files. So there are some files that still need to be imported, but they are under the old template.

My issue stems from when I try to copy the data (paste special, values, anything tried) it gives me an error sometimes: **"The Cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and therefore read-only".**

However, that isn't exactly the case. I've determined that it gives that error when I paste a blank cell onto a new field that has a drop-down with Yes or No. Yet, if I manually go to that cell and give it something blank (hit backspace + enter), it has no problems.

I've tried coding so it copy/paste's each line at a time from workbook to workbook, but my problem still remains for these cells that require a drop-down answer. I'm thinking that these cells need to be coded to actually be "typed" instead of pasted. It can't be a part of pasting the actual range.

Does anyone have an idea of how best to resolve this? Below is my current code, it is copying based on the range(s). It's very sloppy as the only way I can think is to keep switching from workbook to workbook. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, I'm not 100% on how to calculate the LastRow? So I just have it entered manually.

```
Sub MoveText()


For Row = 5 To 962


Workbooks("Data.xls").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Row, 1), Cells(Row, 3)).Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks("blankTemplate.xls").Activate

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells((Row + 1), 1), Cells((Row + 1), 3)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Workbooks("data.xls").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Row, 5), Cells(Row, 29)).Select 'this will select the contents of the active row

Workbooks("blankTemplate.xls").Activate

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells((Row + 1), 5), Cells((Row + 1), 29)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


Next
```

Comment: This doesn't look like "visual-studio".

Comment: I code the VBA in Visual Studio...? Edited to delete the tag if it's incorrect, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub MoveText()

    Dim shtData As Worksheet, shtTempl As Worksheet
    Dim Row As Long

    Set shtData = Workbooks("Data.xls").Sheets("Data") 'or e.g. .Sheets(1)
    Set shtTempl = Workbooks("blankTemplate.xls").Sheets("Data")

    For Row = 5 To 962

        shtTempl.Cells(Row + 1, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = _
                         shtData.Cells(Row, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value

        shtTempl.Cells(Row + 1, 5).Resize(1, 25).Value = _
                        shtData.Cells(Row, 5).Resize(1, 25).Value

    Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't resize the fields we are pasting into =/ It's a specific template that we can't mess with.